# Uncertainty principle and meaning of particle's position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis, quantum-measurements

Suppose we have a particle and a detector. The detector will detect electron position not in a sharp peak but according Heisenberg principle in a peak with a deviation. But what that deviation represents? Why we say that is a standard deviation?

Comment: What makes you think it is the standard deviation? Did you read it somewhere? In some illustration of the principle with a single slit experiment the intensity distribution on the screen may look like a standard deviation, but it isn‘t. Can you please elaborate on what exactly you mean.

Comment: It is stated in the form:$$\sigma_x \cdot \sigma_p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$ My problem is that i can't understand the physical meaning of the deviation. How can you understand what that peak with deviation means?

Comment: When experimental values, e.g. position x and momentum p, show a Gauß distribution then it is the *variance* sigma of the distribution that can be considered a measure of uncertainty. A thorough mathematical derivation leads to the principle in the form you stated, but this is beyond my expertise, so I can’t give a proper answer.

Comment: You seem to imply $\sigma_x\sigma_p$ applies to a *single* measurement, which it does not.